# Export mdb to gdb or make a merge between multiple mdb with same structure

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, convert, merge

I have more than 200 .mdb files with the same structure and I need integrate all in one .mdb but I don't know how, I found a tool that can do it but it works with .gdb formats only.

I could make an exportation one by one of all mdb database to integrate with the tool but it could take me time.

I think there has to be a better solution.

The result that I want is have a merge .shp or .gdb or .mdb (doesn't matter what file type ) with all the information of my 200 .mdb files.

Comment: This is the sort of task where python could come to the rescue.  Do you have any skills in python?  Alternatively, [FME](http://www.safe.com) could do it with minimal effort.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a similar issue. It seems like it shouldn't matter whether your source databases are MDB or GDB.

The script comes in a few parts.

1. It is simplest to put all your MDB/GDB into the same directory. Create a simple script that lists all MDB/GDB within a directory. Return the list.
2. Import the list into a new script which iterates through it, either copying source files that do not yet exist in the target GDB - else fieldmapping the tables within them to append that data to the target file with the same name.
3. Customize the script for your schema.